# From popup to sidebar in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I want to convert an application I have developed from displaying charts in a popup to a sidebar using bootstrap.

Its not as easy as I thought. Getting stuff to go in a popup is relatively easy but I'm not sure where to begin in adapting my code to send the D3 graphic in the chart div object.

I would appreciate suggestions to get me started.

The bootstrap part:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8">
    <div id="map"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
    <div id="chart"></div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

The leaflet relevant part:

```
var onEachFeature_LMA = function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
            layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: zoomToFeature
        });

var div = $('<div class="popupGraph" style="width: 450px; height:350px;"><svg/></div>')[0];

var popup = L.popup({maxWidth:450}).setContent(div);
            layer.bindPopup(popup);
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to iH8, I just modified his code to use the defined div:

```
    layer.on('click', function () {
    // Remove current content
    $('#chart').empty();
    // Append new content
    $('#chart').append(div);
});

var div = $('<div class="popupGraph" style="width: 475px; height:350px;"><svg/></div>')[0];
```

**Edit2**

So, I had to modify iH8's code with a suggestion from a colleague to make it work. Here's what he came up with:

```
function onEachFeatureInd(feature, layer) {
layer.on({
    mouseover: highlightFeature,
    mouseout: resetHighlightInd,
    click: function (e) {
            zoomToFeature(e);
// Remove current content
            $('#chart').empty();
            // Append new content
            $('#chart').append(div);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the layer's click event in the onEachFeature method to append the div to the chart element in your DOM:

```
var onEachFeature_LMA = function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: function (e) {
            zoomToFeature(e);
            setChart(e);
        }
    });
});

function setChart(e) {
    e.target.on('click', function () {
        // Remove current content
        $('#chart').empty();
        // Append new content
        $('#chart').append('<div class="popupGraph" style="width: 450px; height:350px;"><svg/></div>');
    });
}
```

Comment: How do you preserve the mouseover and zoomtofeature in the same onEachFeature? the 'click' event works but I'm not sure how to keep the other elements as well.

Comment: Rewrote my example using your original method.

Comment: Thank you iH8, this definitely put me on the path to solve it. I have edited my post with the final solution. Thank you again!